# Distribution of convergent sum of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

Let $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be an i.i.d. sequence of random variables that are distributed uniformly on $\{\pm 1\}$.

Define $$Y=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{X_n}{n}$$ Can anything meaningful be said about the distribution of $Y$? I know that the sum converges almost always (w.p. $1$) and that the distribution will be symmetric around $0$, but I couldn't find anything else.

Comment: It is easy to see that, $$\varphi_Y(y) = \prod_{k=1}^\infty\cos\left(\frac yn\right)$$ I am not sure that is meaningful or not.

Comment: It's a fact that $Y$ is atomless, in the sense that $P(Y=a)=1$ for each real $a$, but this is not easy to prove.

Comment: Are they independant ?